# Identify this sorcerer spell

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

What is that spell that sorcerers (I believe) use to spam-tag enemies?

The spell is kinda stormy (purple). It creates a round wave around the caster. Most of the casters used a staff and the animation shows it being pointed towards the sky.

I think one of the spell's morphs changes the spell to fire, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I guess you mean the spell "Force Pulse" (morph of Force Shock). It depends on the type of Staff equipped what elemental damage it delivers. http://deltiasgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Force-Shock-Force-Pulse.jpg

Comment: No. The spell I'm speaking about isn't sending a bolt-like towards a target but is making a wave around the caster.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, wrong spell. The heat here drives me crazy. :D The next spell on the same skill line should be the right one: http://deltiasgaming.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Impulse.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The skill you're looking for is *Impulse*

First take a look at the screenshot from the game:

[image]

This is from the **Destruction staff** skill line, which means that any class can use this spell. At the time of launch on PC this spell has been widely used on *Dragonknights* as *Dunmers* with a Flame staff equipped as this provided some nice passives for it.

Destruction staffs can be one of three types: Fire, frost and lightning. Depending on which you chose, the animation is colored differently (flames, ice ring, electricity) and the effects applied do also change for it.

I recommend you to use a flame staff for PvP, as this elemental type does more damage to Vampires, which are also common.

The morphs are *Elemental Ring* (adds damage over time) and *Pulsar* (reduces enemies' max health).

You can look it up [on this wiki page](http://elderscrollsonline.wiki.fextralife.com/Impulse) if you need further information.

Below is a picture demonstrating the effect with an equipped Lightning staff:

[image]

*Picture sources in order: deltiasgaming.com, nomadicgamer.files.wordpress.com*